# Go r.FormValue is empty

Tags: html, go, request, return-value

I got an html form where I put values and insert them into the database. but when I insert them the values appear in the db like "".

This is how I insert the values:

```
title, author, description := r.Form("title"), r.FormValue("author"), r.FormValue("description")

    fmt.Println(title, author, description)

    rows, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO apps (title, author, description) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
        title, author, description)
    PanicIf(err)

    defer rows.Close()

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/myapps", http.StatusFound)

    db.Close()
```

Html :

```
<form action="/apps" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="/myapps">
        <input type="button" value="Return" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </a>
</form>
```

There is maybe something wrong with the formvalues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call [r.ParseForm()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) first before you could use  `r.Form` / `r.PostForm`.

From: http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/request.go#L168

```
// Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
// field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
// This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
// The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
Form url.Values

// PostForm contains the parsed form data from POST or PUT
// body parameters.
// This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
// The HTTP client ignores PostForm and uses Body instead.
PostForm url.Values
```

Comment: Should I add these at my .go file on the header?

Comment: You call it in every handler, typically as one of the first things you do. Make sure to check the error.

Comment: You just need to use `r.ParseForm()` right before you call anything that uses `r.Form`, so the line before `title, author, description :=...`

Comment: @OneOfOne yes, I used it like this:  r.ParseForm()

    title, author, description := r.FormValue("title"), r.FormValue("author"), r.FormValue("description")
    
    fmt.Println(title, author, description) but didnt get the values, keep again " ".

Comment: Maybe post more code? I tested with http://play.golang.org/p/M2eqO1Ib9A and it works as intended.

Comment: As of 1.6, [FormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue)